# Use value of javascript variable within html page

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to make an html header which automatically changes the number on the header countdown style. I have a working javascript variable which returns the days until my event. How can I pull the number calculated by the variable "daysUntil" into a span id called countdown in html page?

I searched for a solution and found a few answers regarding getElementById but was unsure how to implement it. I am JUST barely learning so thanks in advance if its a really basic question!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Countdown</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script>
    var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
    var d2 = new Date("2016/11/28")  // some date
    var diff = Math.abs(d2-d1)/(1000*60*60*24);
    var daysUntil = Math.ceil(diff)
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav" id="top">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">COUNTDOWN</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="connect.html">Connect with Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="clearfix" id="content">
  <div class="left">
    <h1>T Minus <span id="countdown"></span>days!</h1>
<!-- The rest of the code is omitted-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your `<script>` after your countdown element.

[See live demo](http://jsbin.com/mupipayego/2/edit?html,output)

```
... 
<div class="left">
    <h1>T Minus <span id="countdown"></span>days!</h1>

    <script>
    var d1 = new Date(); //"now"
    var d2 = new Date("2016/11/28")  // some date
    var diff = Math.abs(d2-d1)/(1000*60*60*24);
    var daysUntil = Math.ceil(diff);

    var countdown = document.getElementById('countdown');        
    countdown.textContent = daysUntil + ' ';

    </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I see you added a space there in the textContent + ' ' which I will just add in the h1 itself for simplicity. This was extremely helpful, especially the jsbin link!

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

This is the way to go, as well, as `innerText` and `innerHTML`.

The simple example would go as follow

`document.getElementById('countdown').textContent = daysUntil.toString()`